# why am i getting this error:Type Subscription is not assignable to type FirebaseListObservable<any>?

Tags: angular, ionic2, angularfire2

I am trying to retrieve data from the `/users` list and getting this error:

> Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type
>   'FirebaseListObservable'. Property '$ref' is missing in type
>   'Subscription'.

below is my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable  } from 'angularfire2/database';



@Injectable()
export class FbauthserviceProvider {

  user : FirebaseListObservable<any>;   
  email: string;

  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public afDb: AngularFireDatabase) {
    console.log('Hello FbauthserviceProvider Provider');
  }

  signup_with_username(email: string,password: string){
    this.email = email;

    this.user = this.afDb.list('/users', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'email',
        equalTo: this.email,
      },
      preserveSnapshot: true
    }).subscribe(snapshots => {
      let user_data = [];
      snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
        user_data.push(snapshot.val());
      });
      console.log(user_data);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is rife with anti-patterns and unnecessary parts.

First, don't use `preserveSnapshot`. You don't need to with AngularFire. You can subscribe directly to the array itself that is emitted by the `FirebaseListObservable`. Once you have it, there is no need to iterate over it and push its elements onto some other array--you already have the array, which you can use as is, or map, or store (but see below), or whatever. So just write:

```
this.user = this.afDb.list('/users', {
  query: {
    orderByChild: 'email',
    equalTo: this.email,
  }})
}).subscribe(users => {
  console.log("users are", users);
});
```

But there's still a problem here. `this.user` is not what you might thing: it will be the **subscription** returned by `subscribe`. You can't do anything with it other than unsubscribe. If you want to "unwrap" the list of users and store it as a local static property, you need to assign it in the `subscribe` handler, where it's available:

```
.subscribe(users => {
  console.log("users are", users);
  this.users = users;
})
```

However, unwrapping the observable and storing it in a static property is (often) an anti-pattern. The problem is that you have no idea when it's going to be ready. In the best case, you'll have to wrap places in your template where it's used with `*ngIf="users"`, or qualify references to it in the template with the existential operator `?` as in `users?.length` (which is not AoT-friendly).

Instead, leave the observable as is, and dereference it directly in your template using the `async` pipe:

```
this.users$ = this.afDb.list('/users', {
  query: {
    orderByChild: 'email',
    equalTo: this.email,
  }});

<div *ngFor="let user of users$ | async">
  User is {{user.name}}
</div>
```

Here I'm following the convention of suffixing properties representing observables with the `$`, which is useful to maintain your sanity.

If you only want the names, then you can map the observable itself to create an observable of arrays of names:

```
this.names$ = this.users$.map(users => users.map(user => user.name));
```

Note that these two `map` calls are different. The first is mapping the **observable** into a new observable. The second is mapping the array of users **emitted** by the observable into a new array containing the names. Now in your template:

```
<li *ngFor="let name of names$">{{name}}</li>
```

The discussion above relates to components. In your case, you have a service. In general, it is an anti-pattern for services to subscribe to some observable and store the value in a static local property. The problem is that components referencing that property on the service will not be updated. Instead, your service should expose observables, and let the consumer--usually a component--dereference/unwrap them.

To find users whose mobile numbers match, you can still stay in the world of observables:

```
this.matchingUsers$ = this.users$.map(users => users.filter(user => user.mobile === mobile));
```

which will create an observable of arrays of users with matching mobile numbers, which will empty if none match. Some consuming template could use this as

```
<div *ngFor="let matchingUser of userService.matchingUsers$ | async">
  Found matching user {{user.name}}
</div>
```

or

```
<div *ngIf="userService.matchingUsers$ | async as matchingUsers">
  <div *ngIf="!matchingUsers.length">
    Sorry, no matching users.
  </div>
</div>
```

and so on. Note that this `as` syntax requires Angular 4.

That's the Angular/observable/AngularFirebase way.

Comment: Thxxx @torazaburo for the detailed explanation. this user data i am retrieving is not from the authentication user section. it's simply from my databaase where i store user profile info in '/users'. i need to do some checks with the user's number. therefore i have to get that one user data and unwrap to check the mobile number if it matches.

Answer (score 0):

`subscribe` function returns a Subscription object.

You are assigning to a `FirebaseListObservable` reference.
Instead subscribe after assigning if you need to reuse the observable.

```
this.user = this.afDb.list('/users',{

    query: {

        orderByChild: 'email',
        equalTo: this.email,
    },
    preserveSnapshot: true
})
this.user.subscribe(snapshots =>{

        let user_data = [];
        snapshots.forEach(snapshot=>{
            user_data.push(snapshot.val());
        });
```

Comment: thxx @suraj for the answer. I get snapshot.val() is not a function error

Comment: depends on what is `snapshot`? can you log it?you will have to debug a bit

Comment: actually by doing snapshots.forEach(snapshot =>{ console.log(snapshot.email) } i get the value!! thx a lot @suraj. but the only problem is i want to send the user data (snapshot) to the array.

Comment: so directly push `snapshot` or directly assign `snapshots` array to user_data?

Comment: because snapshot is showing not just the data in object array it is also showing some other stuffs like $exists, $function(), and other unwanted things..so when i push it to the array i still get the same bunch of dataobject+ other stuffs